# Encoding issue with printing the degree symbol on a word document using docx

Tags: python, python-2.7, ms-word

Trying to add the degree symbol to a word document using the python docx and my function is defined like this:

```
def convert_decimal_degrees2DMS(self,value):
    #value = math.fabs(value)
    degrees = int(value)
    submin = math.fabs( (value - int(value) ) * 60)
    minutes = int(submin)
    subseconds = round(math.fabs((submin-int(submin)) * 60),1)
    subseconds = int(subseconds)
    self.angle = str(degrees) + " Degrees " + str(minutes) + " Minutes " +\
               str(subseconds)[0:2] + " Seconds "
    #self.angle = str(degrees) + "-" + str(minutes) + "-" + str(subseconds)
    #return str(degrees) + "-" + str(minutes) + "-" + str(subseconds)
    #degree = u'\N{DEGREE SIGN}'.encode('utf-8')
    return "{0}{1}{2}'{3}''".format(degrees,u'°'.encode('cp1252'),minutes,subseconds)
```

and the error that I keep getting is this:

```
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 921, in lxml.etree._Element.text.__set__ (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:41467)
  File "apihelpers.pxi", line 652, in lxml.etree._setNodeText (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:18888)
  File "apihelpers.pxi", line 1335, in lxml.etree._utf8 (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:24701)
ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'print_exc'" in <function _remove at 0x01E0F770> ignored
```

I have tried to many variations and nothing has worked and I am afraid it might be beucase of my lack of understanding about encode that I am not getting this.

Comment: What the function is returning is what I add to the word document.

Answer (score 0):

`u'°'.encode('cp1252')` returns a byte-string (of type `str`) equivalent to `'\xb0'`.  Similarly, in other places you are converting things to `str`.  The error is telling you that you need strings of type `unicode` (Unicode codepoints) instead of `str` (bytes).  The degree sign itself is likely not the problem.

The solution is to simply provide Unicode strings instead: so `u'°'` instead of `u'°'.encode('cp1252')`, and

```
self.angle = degrees + u" Degrees " + minutes + u" Minutes " + \
               subseconds[0:2] + u" Seconds "
```

instead of

```
self.angle = str(degrees) + " Degrees " + str(minutes) + " Minutes " +\
               str(subseconds)[0:2] + " Seconds "
```

(assuming that `degrees` etc. are of type `unicode` instead of `str`).  Note the `u''` syntax for Unicode strings as opposed to the `''` syntax for byte-strings.

The one thing you have to remember about including non-ASCII characters in Python source is the encoding header documented in [PEP-0263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).  So you would follow the shebang with an encoding declaration:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
```

Just keep in mind, using PEP 0263 doesn't magically make the duality of `str` vs `unicode` go away.  `'°'` will be whatever `str` (byte-string) is found in the source code file on disk and therefore not necessarily of length 1 (if ISO-8859-1, it's equivalent to `'\xb0'`, if DOS cp437, to `'\xf8'`, if UTF-8, to `'\xc2\xb0'`).  Whereas `u'°'` will be Unicode codepoint `U+00B0` regardless of the encoding of the source code.

Here's an illustration of non-ASCII characters in source code.  It matters for this example to see the actual bytes of the source code.  The source code is UTF-8 encoded, so `'°'` has length 2; it is after all a byte-string.

```
$ cat x.py 
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

print repr('°')
print len('°')
print len(u'°')

$ od -c -txC x.py
0000000    #   !   /   u   s   r   /   b   i   n   /   p   y   t   h   o
           23  21  2f  75  73  72  2f  62  69  6e  2f  70  79  74  68  6f
0000020    n  \n   #       -   *   -       c   o   d   i   n   g   :    
           6e  0a  23  20  2d  2a  2d  20  63  6f  64  69  6e  67  3a  20
0000040    U   T   F   -   8       -   *   -  \n  \n   p   r   i   n   t
           55  54  46  2d  38  20  2d  2a  2d  0a  0a  70  72  69  6e  74
0000060        r   e   p   r   (   '   °  **   '   )  \n   p   r   i   n
           20  72  65  70  72  28  27  c2  b0  27  29  0a  70  72  69  6e
0000100    t       l   e   n   (   '   °  **   '   )  \n   p   r   i   n
           74  20  6c  65  6e  28  27  c2  b0  27  29  0a  70  72  69  6e
0000120    t       l   e   n   (   u   '   °  **   '   )  \n            
           74  20  6c  65  6e  28  75  27  c2  b0  27  29  0a
$ python x.py
'\xc2\xb0'
2
1
```