# Can't get a degree symbol into raw_input

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding, python-unicode

The problem in my code looks something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

deg = u'°'
print deg
print '40%s N, 100%s W' % (deg, deg)
codelim = raw_input('40%s N, 100%s W)? ' % (deg, deg))
```

I'm trying to generate a raw_input prompt for delimiter characters inside a latitude/longitude string, and the prompt should include an example of such a string. `print deg` and `print '40%s N, 100%s W' % (deg, deg)` both work fine -- they return "°" and "40° N, 100° W" respectively -- but the `raw_input` step fails every time. The error I get is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[rest of the path]\scratch.py", line 5, in  <module>
    x = raw_input(' %s W")? ' % (deg))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb0' in position 1:
ordinal not in range(128)
```

I thought I'd have solved the problem by adding the encoding header, as instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091480/encoding-issue-with-printing-the-degree-symbol-on-a-word-document-using-docx) (and indeed that did make it possible to print the degree sign at all), but I'm still getting Unicode errors as soon as I add an otherwise-safe string to `raw_input`. What's going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try encoding the prompt string to `stdout`s encoding before passing it to raw input

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import sys

deg = u'°'

prompt = u'40%s N, 100%s W)? ' % (deg, deg)
codelim = raw_input(prompt.encode(sys.stdout.encoding))
```

> 40° N, 100° W)?

Comment: Newbie mistake. Oops. Consider it fixed.

Comment: Now to figure out _why_ it works. Hm. This is highly educational. Thanks!

Comment: The string is unicode but `raw_input` isn't expecting unicode (it's probably expecting 'utf-8') so it misinterprets the bytes passed to it and you get garbage. You can take the unicode string and reencode it, `sys.stdin.encoding` returns the encoding used by `stdin` for that particular system, so your code is now portable than if you'd hard coded `prompt.encode("utf-8")`

Comment: Note a correction to the answer. It should be `sys.stdout.encoding` not `sys.stdin.encoding`. Since they almost certainly return the same thing it will be fine but now its strictly more correct.

Comment: Aha, I get it. Thanks!